# Making a DLL into a COM component

Tags: c++, com

I'm new to COM so this maybe a stupid question, but I'll ask it anyway. :)

As far as I understand, in order to make a DLL COM we need to define its interface in a .idl file, compile it with the MIDL compiler and then simply implement the classes that use the defined interfaces. Then we need to expose the `DllRegisterServer`, `DllUnregisterServer` and `DllGetClassObject`. and it should be enough, right?

But I did all this and when I try to check it in a client C++ program, my visual studio says 
(on the #import statement) that it can't find the tlh file...

This is how my .idl looks like:

```
import "someIdl.idl";

[
    uuid(some-guid-Num1),
    version(1.0),
    helpstring("The library's description")
]
library LibName
{
    importlib("stdole2.tlb");
    [
        uuid(some-guid-Num2),
        helpstring("Some Description")
    ]
    coclass ClassName
    {       
        interface Interface_defined_in_someIdl;
    }
};
```

Am I missing something in the .idl?  Did I get the COM making process wrong?

Comment: My COM is a little rusty but did you remember to use regsvr32 to register the DLL?

Comment: I do. I register both GUIDs (the library's and class's) to Current User\Classes\CLSID. Is the library's GUID supposed to be registered to another location?

Comment: But I think it's not it. I have another COM DLL that I downloaded, unregistered it and didn't get the error...

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I didn't embed the TLB file into the DLL as resource.